# Laravel 5.3 - blank white screen after cloning repository

Tags: laravel-5.3

I have cloned the repository locally to the homestead server. I have `generated application key`, run `composer install and update`, gave the permission to storage and bootstrap/cache, checked the `php` version on `homestead`, it is `7.1.3` but I am still getting blank white screen with no errors. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the log files in storage/logs contain anything interesting?

Comment: there is only .gitignore file there

Comment: That indicates a permission problem on storage/logs. You probably have some kind of error that Laravel wants to tell you about, but the logging fails and everything just gives up. Check the permissions on storage/logs and verify that your web-user (perhaps `www-data`) can write to it.